# Javascript variable is changing encoding when sent from Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am sending a variable via flask render_template("index.html", data=data).
In my server.py data looks like this:

```
data = [{'value': 0.0}, {'value': 0.0}, {'value': 0.0}, {'value': 0.001}, {'value': 0.001}, {'value': 0.001},...]
```

but on the javascript side console I get this when I do `console.log({{data}});`:

```
[{&#39;value&#39;: &#39;0.0&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: &#39;0.0&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: &#39;0.0&#39;}, {&#39;value&#39;: &#39;0.001&#39;}, ...
```

Why is this happening? How do I get the data in an object format?

Comment: Can you show the line where you are sending the data in server.py?